# Why will delete query not recognise the value in column header process_status in table?

Tags: ms-access, sql-delete, delete-row

Why will the query not recognize the value of column header `process_status` in table?

I am using below query to try and delete rows where the `process_status` is **"L"** only however when I run the query the database asks me to enter a value for “L” as opposed to looking for that value in the column – Why is this?

```sql
DELETE SELECT UFA_Linked.*, UFA_Linked.ACCPED_ACCOUNT_NO    
FROM UFA_Linked    
WHERE (((UFA_Linked.ACCPED_ACCOUNT_NO) In (
    SELECT [Account_No] 
    FROM [deals_extract] 
    WHERE [deal_type_description]<> "Term Extension" AND [deal_length_years]>5 AND [process_status] = “L”)));
```

i have tried re-arranging the query as the same principle is working for "Term Extension". 
Also tried not in ("all", "values", "other", "than" L) but the query does then not recognise the subsequent values.

Not having much luck searching for existing answers - probably phrasing my questions poorly.

Comment: Does it work as you wish if you change `[process_status] = “L”` to `[process_status] = 'L'`?

Comment: If you want to delete, do not use `DELETE SELECT` ... use just `DELETE` there.

Comment: You might find it helpful to use the query Wizard. Having done this you can then copy and use the SQL wherever needed, e.g. in a DoCmd.RunSQL procedure.

Comment: Thanks guys.  using 'L' has worked.

Comment: I did try the query wizard Great Cosby which i forgot to mention however I couldn't figure out how to choose a value in a column - could only choose the column header so it didn't help me.  Still a great tool to know about - thanks for suggesting it.

Answer (score 0):

You use `“L”` quotes instead of `"L"`. `“”` - are symbols like others, not special ones, required for strings and Access tries to find column `[“L”]`, cannot find it and considers it as parameter and asks you to enter the value for it. Replace quotes.

Comment: This is going to sound very stupid but i don't understand how they are different?  I used shift & 2 for both - I can see that they look different but in fact I typed them the same way? " " "  "   Thanks

Comment: Where did you edit the query text? MS Word by default automatically replaces strait quotes to paired ones. In your example used paired quotes, and letter L didn't highlighted as string, this web site also doesn't recognizes paired quotes as string delimiters.